# flutter splash screen is blurry on physical device

Tags: flutter, dart

My goal is to show a splash screen while app initializes.

So I used this package : `flutter_native_splash: 0.1.9`

And as per flutter_native_splash documentation on pub.dev, I created this file as required:

```
flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/splash.png
  color: "#ffffff"
  fill: true
  # android_disable_fullscreen: true
```

and in terminal i ran this command:

`flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create`

the package generated me the images in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xdpi, drawable-xxdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi

now i am able to use this splash screen successfully but the problem is that the generated image is very blurry on physical device when i test...

is there any guidelines on how to draw this image from the start?

its just a simple black image with centered text...lets say for examle "Splash Screen"

**i use figma for drawing** and i export the file as SVG.

so my questions are:

1. should i specify width and height for the canvas that i draw inside?!
2. should i specify a fixed font size for the text...if so...suppose that there are two texts...centered one...and a subtitle beneath it.

i manipulated the font size many times but every time the generated image is blurry...

any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

this is screenshot from figma while i am drawing the image:

[figma screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eptfZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Make a splash screen background image of size 1080*1920, add it into the drawable folder (android/app/src/main/res/drawable).

2.) Add below code into your android's styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

3.) Add below code in AndroidManifest.xml inside  tag

```
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

4.) Add meta-data in your first activity.

```
        <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
```

Comment: alright...i will try this "background image of size 1080*1920" and revise again step 3 and 4....any ideas about which font size to use in writing text in splash screen ?!

Comment: To add text on background image you should create a widget. Add your background image in asset folder and access like - 
  Widget splash() {
    return Center(
        child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          foregroundDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/splashbg.png'), fit: BoxFit.fill),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          'App Name',
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
Use the widget in MyApp stateful widget.

Comment: thanks for this explanation...but i am asking about which font size to choose when writing text on the splash screen that will be used in drawable folders...the background image and the text on top of it will be all an xml file

Comment: Approx 70px font size.
But It might stretch or shrink as per the device resolution. Better to use what i said in last comment.

Comment: i accepted your answer as you are providing so much helpful info...thanks again :)...however your approach in last comment can be achieved yes...no stretching...no shringking...all is good....but i was looking for a solution for tthe streatch and shrinking problems....this is the main problem i am facing